# Logging source interface

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios

I recently noticed issue with "logging source-interface" command on Cisco 2960 series switches (not every 2960 switch). Problem seems to appear after issuing "logging source-interface vlan200" (where vlan200 is my management interface of switch) - after that command is not placed in running config and syslog generate message:

> %PARSE_RC-4-PRC_NON_COMPLIANCE: `logging source-interface vlan200'

Have you ever had similiar problem to this? Thank you for every answer.

mfx

Comment: BTW. iOS version is: 15.0(2)SE5 C2960-LANLITEK9-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obviously some kind of Cisco IOS bug, you can googled a lot of such things, for examplehttps://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCsq54507

Because it is internal Cisco IOS bug, you cannot fix this in the some logical straight way. If you have TAC support, you can open TAC case. Also try to change IOS (it should help you and this is first that TAC will ask you if you create the case)

If you cannot create TAC case or change IOS, you can try this: 
 - change vlan id, if it is possible
 - change anything for this vlan (description, some parameters, etc..)
 - shutdown this interface before this command and turn on after

According to my experience something of this could help you (or could not, if you are not lucky).

Hope this helps